# tycho is ignoring my splash screen

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tycho, eclipse-rse

in my app, i have define a splash screen via product file, and when I start the application, the splash is shown as expected.
but, after I generated a build with tycho (via hudson), the config.ini of my application ends up as follow:

```
osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/br
```

and the splash screen is never shown. So. I have to edit the file manually and set this line to

```
osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/my_plugin_id
```

any ideas? any workaround?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the tycho tutorial [1] which has a working splash screen example [2].

[1] http://www.eclipsecon.org/2013/sessions/building-eclipse-plug-ins-and-rcp-applications-tycho

[2] https://github.com/jsievers/tycho-demo/tree/master/exercises/Exercise_05_Solution

Comment: my hierarchi is a little bit different. i have 3 projects: myId.feature (which contais my target file), myId.plugin and myId (this one have the product file). i've configured my product's pom like the example, but tycho keep saying that couldn't find my product file. plus, the splash didn't showed up too. edit: i'm using tycho 0.13.0